# Can we catch URL of an AJAX call on click of button in another function

Tags: jquery, url, fusioncharts

Actually I am working with fusion chart where I have used the `link` attribute like this:

```
<set label='Som Deva1' value='2' link='newchart-xmlurl-/project/reportData/getdata?start=01/02/2016&end=29/02/2016&filterLevel=4&filterType=4:61'/>
<set label='Som Deva2' value='3' link='newchart-xmlurl-/project/reportData/getdata?start=01/02/2016&end=29/02/2016&filterLevel=5&filterType=4:61'/>
```

When it draws a chart its legends becomes clickable. I just want to know which legends is clicked. I can identify if I am able to catch url of clicked legend.

How can I catch URl of clicked legend?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know which legends is clicked. I can identify if I am able to catch url of clicked legend.

By using delegated event handler you can get the link of clicked legend from all the charts (no matter when its drawn into HTML) this way. Also you can narrow the event delegation to fewer elements by adding more information in the selector.

```
$('body').on('click','set',function(){
        var currLink = $(this).attr('link');
        alert(currLink );
    });
```

Comment: I want only clicked one's url not all

Comment: Yes, thats what it does, When ever you click it will give you an alert with the clicked one's url . Use can replace that with your code and use it

Comment: console.log(currLink) is `click [object Object]`

Comment: its working fine for me, Here https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/46384p80/ check this fiddle I made for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between legend items and data plots. The link you have configured is applicable to the data plots and not the legend. Even if you do not define the links the legend item should be clickable. Legend Item in Multi Series chart represents `dataset`.

Please check the the corresponding event [legendItemClicked](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-legendItemClicked). Here you should find two values in the second parameter (`dataOb`). These are `datasetName` and `dataIndex`. This you can use to get further insight.

If you want to capture drill down specific events. Please check [beforeLinkedItemOpen](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-beforeLinkedItemOpen), [linkedItemOpened](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events.html#event-linkedItemOpened) etc.

Hope this helps.